# Knitr with interactive user interface

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to write a Rmarkdown code in which the user interactivelly insert an excel table and, then a report is automatically generated. First, in the YAML I've wrote:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "Test"
output: html_document
params: 
  data: 
    label: "Insert your data:"
    value: results.csv
    input: file
---
```

Then, in the chunk 1 I've used:

````
```{r ,warning= FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE }
library(tidyverse)
rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = 'ask')
df = as.data.frame(readxl::read_excel(params$data))
```
````

While running this code aforementioned, the navigator opens with a browser to input the file, and there are two buttons "cancel" and "save" (should it not be 'Knit'?)

When I 'save', the output is: "*Error params object already exists in knit environment so can't be overwritten by render params*"

Therefore, I've tried:

````
```{r ,warning= FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE }
    library(tidyverse)
    rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = 'ask', envir = new.env())
    df = as.data.frame(readxl::read_excel(params$data))
```
````

Again, I insert the data file and the output is:
*Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) :
Duplicate chunk label 'setup', which has been used for the chunk:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
Calls:  ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block*

I'm not finding the issue and why it is happening.
Could someone help me?